# How not to hyphenate inside a command?

Tags: hyphenation

I have a requirement that certain words should be formatted separately in the main text. For this, I have written a new command

`\newcommand{\concept}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\texttt{#1}}}`

I don't want the words that will be written inside `\concept{}` command to be hyphenated. They can be pushed to the next line, but not hyphenated.
What are my options here?

Edit 1: Added the packages in the MWE which shows the hyphenation in `\texttt`. I don't need that many entries in one paragraph, just showing how it is breaking inside `tt` environment. Compiling with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{libertine}
 \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Light}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=6.in, textheight=9.25in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\newcommand{\concept}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\texttt{(#1)}}}

\begin{document}

Each step in the development of the \concept{bourgeoisie} was accompanied by a corresponding \concept{political} advance of that class. An \concept{oppressed} class under the sway of the feudal nobility, an armed and self-governing association in the \concept{medieval} \concept{commune}: here independent urban republic (as in Italy and Germany); there taxable “third estate” of the \concept{monarchy} (as in France); afterwards, in the period of manufacturing proper, serving either the \concept{semi-feudal} or the absolute monarchy as a counterpoise against the \concept{nobility}, and, in fact, cornerstone of the great monarchies in general, the \concept{bourgeoisie} has at last, since the establishment of Modern Industry and of the world market, conquered for itself, in the \concept{modern} representative \concept{State}, exclusive political sway. The executive of the modern state is but a committee for managing the common affairs of the whole bourgeoisie. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can always put them in an extra  `mbox` if you want.

Comment: have you tried putting them in a `mbox`? IE `\newcommand{\concept}[1]{\mbox{\textcolor{gray}[\texttt{#1}}}}`?

Comment: Normally, text in `\texttt` is not hyphenated.

Comment: @Moriambar your solution worked, there is a [ instead of  { in your code, rest works fine,

Comment: @egreg yet it was hyphenated, I have added an image to show this

Comment: @Damitr Too few details for making a diagnosis: what document class? What font packages?

Comment: Please provide a MWE that shows the hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg please see the updated question with packages and MWE

Comment: @lblb please check the updated question

Comment: Which tex engine are you using? `pdflatex` gives `\setmonofont` is undefined.  If you are using `laulatex` or `xelatex` then you should not be using `fontenc`.  Even so you example does not produce hyphens in my set-up (texlive 2016).

Comment: @AndrewSwann I am using `xelatex`, thanks for the tip, but the problem still persists. have updated the MWE with `fontspec`, I have MacTeX 2016

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should state that text in the monospaced font should not be hyphenated, which `fontspec` doesn't do by default:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  textwidth=6.in,
  textheight=9.25in,
  marginparsep=7pt,
  marginparwidth=.6in
}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{libertine}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Light}[HyphenChar=None]

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\newcommand{\concept}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\texttt{(#1)}}}

\begin{document}

Each step in the development of the \concept{bourgeoisie} was accompanied 
by a corresponding \concept{political} advance of that class. An 
\concept{oppressed} class under the sway of the feudal nobility, an armed 
and self-governing association in the \concept{medieval} \concept{commune}: 
here independent urban republic (as in Italy and Germany); there taxable 
“third estate” of the \concept{monarchy} (as in France); afterwards, in the 
period of manufacturing proper, serving either the \concept{semi-feudal} or 
the absolute monarchy as a counterpoise against the \concept{nobility}, and, 
in fact, cornerstone of the great monarchies in general, the 
\concept{bourgeoisie} has at last, since the establishment of Modern Industry 
and of the world market, conquered for itself, in the \concept{modern}
representative \concept{State}, exclusive political sway. The executive of
the modern state is but a committee for managing the common affairs of the
whole bourgeoisie. 

\end{document}
```

However, this will give many overfull lines; such paragraphs should be typeset as `\sloppy`; use `sloppypar` to confine the behavior. Using `microtype` reduces the ugliness.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  textwidth=6.in,
  textheight=9.25in,
  marginparsep=7pt,
  marginparwidth=.6in
}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Light}[HyphenChar=None]

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\newcommand{\concept}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\texttt{(#1)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sloppypar}
Each step in the development of the \concept{bourgeoisie} was accompanied 
by a corresponding \concept{political} advance of that class. An 
\concept{oppressed} class under the sway of the feudal nobility, an armed 
and self-governing association in the \concept{medieval} \concept{commune}: 
here independent urban republic (as in Italy and Germany); there taxable 
“third estate” of the \concept{monarchy} (as in France); afterwards, in the 
period of manufacturing proper, serving either the \concept{semi-feudal} or 
the absolute monarchy as a counterpoise against the \concept{nobility}, and, 
in fact, cornerstone of the great monarchies in general, the 
\concept{bourgeoisie} has at last, since the establishment of Modern Industry 
and of the world market, conquered for itself, in the \concept{modern}
representative \concept{State}, exclusive political sway. The executive of
the modern state is but a committee for managing the common affairs of the
whole bourgeoisie.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the `texttt` text is still hyphenated (even if it shouldn't) or whenever you have a similar task, you could try `mbox`ing it, ie:

```
 \newcommand{\concept}[1]{\mbox{\textcolor{gray}{\texttt{#1}}}}
```

A small sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\concept}[1]{\mbox{\textcolor{gray}{\texttt{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
A pre-test question about how to find distance from the Earth to the Sun \concept{(collaboration)}\concept{(prior knowledge)}
\end{document}
```

with the result

[image]